# Strange jquery dropdown menu issue?

Tags: jquery, yii

I have a very strange bug in a website: http://brightsystems.eu/vini/index.php/en
The main menu sometimes gets messed up. The strangest thing, if I double click on the browser refresh, the chances that the page will be displayed properly afterwards. There isn't really a method to anything, just that usually during a session the menu gets messed up all of a sudden.

While developing the site locally, this was never an issue. I'm pretty sure the CSS is ok, otherwise it wouldn't be displayed correctly ever at all.

I've put in a quick fix that refreshes each page as soon as it loads, which works, but this is hardly a durable solution.

The main menu is created in jquery and the site using yii framework.

Anyone have similar experiences or solutions?

Comment: Whoa, I'd re-think that whole menubar you've got going. I'm on a mid-2010 laptop and that site is SLOW dude.

Comment: strange header <!DOCTYkuluPE HTML>.
This can cause unpredictible glitches with your page layout.

Comment: Hi thanks for quick replies, The speed is quite reasonable on my end and I'm on a late 2008 machine, but I do agree, perhaps making such a dropdown manually would be at less less bulky.
Stupid doctype, already fixed it once (and now again) but still no dice...

Answer (score 1):

Mega-menu calculates the top offset of dropdown automaticly from main container height.

```
http://brightsystems.eu/vini/js/jquery.dcmegamenu.1.3.3.js line 200
var menuHeight = $('> li > a',$dcMegaMenuObj).outerHeight(true);
```

The possible reason of glitch is that sometimes `menuHeight` is calculated before the main menu is rendered completely. And possible solutions are:

1) `<ul id="main-menu" class="mega-menu">` should have fixed height, defined in css (34px or so).

2) mega-menu should be initiated after some little delay to be sure that main menu is completely rendered. (bad solution)

**Edit:**

try to fix it in green.css

```
.green ul.mega-menu li a.dc-mega {
    position: relative;
    height: 34px;                 <-- add this 
}
```

Comment: Actually, It your solution doesn't work, and nor does my orignal solution. I guess adding a height here and there slowed everything down, rather solving the actual issue.
I'm giving it another go, any further suggestions welcome, and thanks again